# how to change the color of the navbar after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, bootstrap-4

I want my navbar to be transparent, but when the user scrolls a bit I want it to change to a solid color and I am using bootstrap for the navbar, I have done the code that is needed with javascript.

I had this javascript in my HTML file, but it doesn't seems to work and I don't really know why

```
    <script>
      var myNav = document.getElementById("mynav");

      window.onscroll = function() {
          use strict";
          if (document.body.scrollTop >= 100) {
              myNav.classList.add("scroll");
          } else {
              myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
          }
      };
    </script>
```

and I have also added the CSS code.

```css
.scroll {
   background-color: transparent !important;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, it is not displaying any errors, I have also manually put the class and it worked so the problem is from the js code and not the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrollY` property of Window object.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var myNav = document.getElementById("mynav");

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
        myNav.classList.add("scroll");
    } else {
        myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
    }
};
```

```css
.scroll {
   background-color: transparent !important;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.main-container{
  height: 1000px;
}

#mynav{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="mynav" id="mynav">
  Hello World! this is mynav
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i already done the navbar and everything i just need the js but gonna check it

Comment: Focus on js part only.. I have created sample html and css because you have not added yours in your original question..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.scrollY` instead of `document.body.scrollTop`.

```
if (window.scrollY >= 100)
```

You can also use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. It's the html element that actually scrolls, not the body. Typically `document.body.scrollTop` will always be 0.